# Start IIS Express using Service

Tags: c#, service, iis-express

I wanted to start IIS Express with the configuration I wanted on boot. The best way to do this was the start it via a Service. I first tested it using a console application in VS 2013 (C#) by starting IIS Express as a process and killing it on exit. This worked fine.

However when I made it into a service, the service installed fine, and it started automatically but it refused to start IIS Express. I had to stop the service, go to the property of the service I installed and change the Log on option to “This account” enter my username and password, click OK, and start the service. This started the IIS Express and my webserver worked fine from that point onwards.

I have a two part question:

1. Is there something about IIS Express that I need to know which is stopping me from starting it from service?
2. What can I do to start it automatically either programmatically or during the Service installation process (serviceprocessinstaller properties perhaps)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you set the service to automatic with your credentials, it should be starting fine

Comment: Could you not just create a scheduled task that automatically started it?  Why create your own service just to do this specifically?

Comment: Why not just use IIS itself? That's already designed to run as a service.

Comment: @BugFinder, I could, but I need to make an installer that does all of that automatically. I have to either do it programatically or set the credentials on Advanced Installer so it does it during installation process.

Comment: @MartinParkin I will try to create a scheduled task programatically and see if it works. thanks for the suggestions :D

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, because using IIS Express is part of the project :(

Comment: You should be able to do it as part of the installer - depending on the installer used to say run service as user and prompt for details.

Comment: @MartinParkin I couldnt get it to run at startup but it only runs on user log on unfortunately :\ any suggestions

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, there was a way to do it on the installer. Just couldn't find it